# Is Banach fixed point theorem a necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of a fixed point

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, machine-learning, fixed-point-theorems

Banach fixed point theorem requires a contraction mapping from a metric space into itself, but when I was learning some machine learning algorithms, some questions rise above:
 k-means is an algorithm for clustering, it can be proved that this method will converge, but the proof of convergence of the algorithm doesn't involve fixed point theorem. I feel the iteration of the centering point for each cluster in this method is very similar the iteration of the fixed point iteration steps so I tried to prove this convergence using Banach fixed point theorem. However I couldn't construct a contraction mapping in this problem. So I guess  if  the iteration steps in k-means is not a contraction at all. In order to test this assumption, I generate some random number on my computer and use the k-means steps to cluster and calculate the norm distance between each iteration point.To my surprise, it is NOT a contraction!but it does converge in finite steps. I think the convergence shows the existence  of the fixed point under this iteration. So with these facts, can I say the Bananch Fixed point theorem gives a sufficient condition on the existence of a fixed point, but it might not be necessary?

Comment: If you're asking if contraction in each step is necessary for convergence, then yes you're right - it is not necessary

Comment: $\mathbb R$ is a Banach space and $f(x)=2x$ is map with a unique fixed point. It is not a contraction.